# Div equivalent for canvas width:height ratio before styling?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, canvas

When specifying `[width="3"]` and `[height="1"]` on a `<canvas>`, any style height or width applied to the canvas will stretch the other dimension proportionally to the attributes.

This feature is extremely useful, and I'm curious what the alternative is for `<div>`s

I want to use this proportion technique on Bootstrap columns to create responsive row heights

```css
canvas {
  background: green;
  height: 100px;
}

div {
  background: red;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<canvas height="1" width="3"></canvas>
<div height="1" width="3"></div>
```

Comment: Han!, I passed almost one hour trying to find an other element acting like that, but haven't found any... I guess you won't be able to reproduce it with a div though.